# Kotlin function to print all of an Enum's ordinal/name pairs

Tags: generics, kotlin, enums

Something about Enums is confusing me.  I'd like a function to "know" about all the possible Enum ordinal/name mappings, but passing my enum class to a function isn't working right.

`fun printEnumOrdinalAndNames(targetEnumType:???)`

I can hack around it on the calling side with

`println(MY_ENUM_TYPE.values().map { it.ordinal to it.name }.toMap())`

but am not sure if I can somehow pass in a `MY_ENUM_TYPE::class` or similar, I can't get the function signature right to accept **any Enum**.  `printEnumOrdinalAndNames(MY_ENUM_TYPE)` won't compile because it isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function with a `reified` type to do this on any `Enum`. Once you have the class, you can map its `enumContstants` to whatever you'd like (a `Map<String,Int>` in this case), or modify it to print them if you'd like.

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<*>> namesAndOrdinalsOf(): Map<String,Int> =
    T::class.java.enumConstants.map {
        it.name to it.ordinal
    }.toMap()
```

**Edit**: I had no idea that `enumValues<T>()` existed (thanks @Slaw), you can rewrite it like this, as it is simpler:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> namesAndOrdinalsOf(): Map<String,Int> =
    enumValues<T>().map {
        it.name to it.ordinal
    }.toMap()
```

And to use it:

```
enum class Things {
    Grapes,
    Chairs,
    Spectacles
}

fun main() {
    println(namesAndOrdinalsOf<Things>())
}
// Prints: {Grapes=0, Chairs=1, Spectacles=2}
```

Comment: Clearly I don't know how to use reified.  Worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumValues()` to get the constants of an arbitrary `enum`, as described in [Enum Classes - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants). It requires an inline function with a reified type:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> ordinalsAndNamesOf() =
    enumValues<T>().map { it.ordinal to it.name }.toMap()
```

And using it would look like:

```
fun main() {
    println(ordinalsAndNamesOf<Foo>())
}

enum class Foo {
    BAR, BAZ, QUX
}
```